# How to test the non-existence of a file with pytest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, .netrc

I am not a new developer, but I am new to python.

I am modifying an existing routine that checks for a token in an environment variable. I'm modifying it to look in `.netrc` if the token does not exist in the environment and I want to test it, but I can't figure out how to mock a missing file. The code looks like this.

```
def _get_path() -> str:;
    """Get personal access token."""
    pat = os.environ["MY_TOKEN"]
    if not pat:
        try:
            pat = netrc.netrc().authenticators('my.site')[2]
        except netrc.NetrcParseError as ne:
            print(f"Parse error in ${ne.filename} at ${ne.lineno}: ${ne.msg})
        else:
            raise ValueError('No PAT found')
     return pat
```

This defaults to looking for `$HOME/.netrc`, which exists in my environment but may not in another developers environment. It certainly won't exist in the test environment.

I'm pretty sure I can figure out how to test a bad `.netrc` but I just can't seem to figure out how to use pytest, mock or mockito to test for a missing `$HOME/.netrc` regardless of whether or not aa real one exists.

How do I do this?

Edit: To clarify, the testing environment may have the MY_TOKEN variable set and/or may have `$HOME/.netrc` ... how can I test the non-existence of `$HOME/.netrc` regardless of whether or not it exists in the testing environment?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good time to use `if not os.path.exists(filepath):`

Comment: `$HOME/.netrc` exists in my environment ... but perhaps I should check for the existence of .netrc before calling netrc ... but that still doesn't answer how I can test for the non-existence of a file using pytest .